# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I can't get my location through navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (). An error from undefined is not a object appears. Is it what it can be?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(()=>{alert('ok')});
}


render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Hello Maps</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BjGV.png)

Comment: Did the user approve providing their location?

Comment: Yes. add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">

Comment: Where is the code for importing the navigator?